# A question about react state change with input elements

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, setstate

I have a question about React's `useState`, specifically on the way it handles state changes with input elements.

The way I understand it, the way we can control an input's value with useState goes something along this:

```js
const [state,setState] = useState("hello world");

return (
  <input value={state} onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} />
);
```

In this example the value of the input is bound to state.

When the value of the input changes, it triggers a state change using  `setState` functions that in return re-renders the component with a new value for state, reflected in the value of the input.

My question is: How can the input's value change before the state's value changes? Doesn't the input's value bound to the state's value?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but if you're trying to change an input without re-rendering, I would look into the useRef hook.  You can pass the value of the input by accessing ref.current.value without the need to save it to a useState.  https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp

Comment: I'm trying to understand the concept of how can an onChange(which means the value of the input changes) before the state's value changes. Isn't the input's value bound to the state's value? If so, how can the value of the input change before the state's value does?
It's somewhat of a question about how two-way data binding works in react

Comment: The input value changes in two ways: user input, and state changes. The `onChange` handler sets state. The input is re-rendered w/ the new state. If it **didn't** set state you'd see the component render first w/ the new user input, then be overwritten by the component's `value` *uh* value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the `onChange` more like an `oninput`

This is from the react docs.

> onChange: An Event handler function. Required for controlled inputs. Fires immediately when the input’s value is changed by the user (for example, it fires on every keystroke). Behaves like the browser input event.

This means that fact that the user is typing is causing the `onChange` to fire. This is where you are then setting state, which causes a render and that allows you to see the updated value on screen.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the input's value isn't absolutely bound to the state's value.
Or that onChange "predicts" what is going to be the next value of the input based on the user's actions?

Comment: the browser is handling the capturing of the inputed value. React then sends it to you in the `onChange` handler where you apply it to state only so that it can be seen on screen. The actual value being captured is handled by the browser and not react

Comment: @random_guy123 `onChange` doesn't "predict" anything, it is what is fired when there's a change. Whether or not the (state) value is updated depends on the `onChange` handler. Input components are affected by both state and user activity.

Comment: Thank you both for the thorough explanations :)